# Удаление файла по кнопке

Tags: php, html

В корневой директории лежат сгенерированые html файлы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как организовать удаление файла по нажатию на картинку крестика. Исходник на php, СSS стили не прилагаю из за ненадобности.

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename) {



        echo " <div class='item'><img style='margin: 0 auto;' src='dist/img/catalog.png' alt=''/><br>"."<a href='http://dizelist18.ru/lk/$filename\n'>"."$filename\n"."</a><img src='dist/img/delete.png' alt=''/></div><br>";
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Абсолютна та же идеология, что и при сохранении с уникальным именем из вашего предыдущего вопроса. По нажатию на крестик отправляете POST с именем файла запрос на сервер и удаляете командой `unlink`

Comment: @rjhdby вопрос возник по причине того что это отдельная страница. И в которой только 5 строк кода на php. Я прочитал про unlink. Как его привязать в тегу img с картинкой крестика, ссылкой a href или как& пока только просто тег img есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename) {
?>
    <div class='item'>
        <img style='margin: 0 auto;' src='dist/img/catalog.png' alt=''/><br>
        <a href='http://dizelist18.ru/lk/<?php echo $filename?>'>
            <?php echo $filename?>
        </a>
        <img src='dist/img/delete.png' alt='' onclick='delete("<?php echo $filename?>");'/>
   </div><br>
<?php
}
?>
```

Функцию `delete()` делайте по аналогии с функцией отправки формы из вашего прошлого вопроса.

Плюс к тому будет необходим PHP-скрипт на стороне сервера, которому будет отправляться эта форма. Какой-то такой

```
<?php
$filename='/directory/with/files/'.$_POST['filename'];
if(is_file($filename)) unlink($filename);
?>
```

Ну и надо будет побеспокоиться на предмет того, что бы какой нибудь шутник не послал этому скрипту что-то вроде `../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: А если форма и скрипт будут на одной и той же странице? то их просто рядом прописать?

Comment: @Павел можно и так. А вообще, вам бы сначала теорию подучить. Вопросы то задаете прям совсем базовые

Comment: Добавил один код ниже другого, и оно не заработало, картинка некликабельна

Comment: @Павел то, что на ней не изменился курсор всего лишь значит, что вы для нее не выбрали нужный стиль. То, что код не сработал - ну тут миллион вариантов. Откройте в браузере JS-консоль и посмотрите, на что ругается при клике.

Comment: Консоль ничего не пишет, кнопка не тыкабельна

Answer (score 1):

Передавать с сервера аттрибут идентификатора картинки, навроде `"...<img unique_id=\"$img_id\">..."`
А потом ajax-ом обращаешься к файлу, который отвечает за события, происходящие на сервере, либо к отдельному файл, который трет картинку с айдишником из аргументов запроса, посланного через ajax, по той же схеме, как этот айдишник к ней генерился.